# "... get just deserts." Can ambiguity be syntactic and also semantic?

Tags: ambiguity

On the page, but not when spoken, this line has a double meaning:

**"Lost travellers in Egypt get just deserts."**

The key word is the homograph ( or homogram) **deserts** which can be abstract , (when stressed on the first syllable) or concrete (stressed on the second);

Should this example be categorised as syntactic ambiguity, or semantic ambiguity, or lexical ambiguity? Can it be all three?

Syntactic Ambiguity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity

> desert:    arid land with  sparse vegetation; [see Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desert) (abbreviated)
>
> just deserts: what one deserves, especially  punishment:  [see Oxford
>   Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/get-or-receive-one%27s-just-deserts)  (abbreviated)

Comment: +1 for making me aware that "just deserts" is actually written with one "s" and derives from an archaic meaning of desert rather then cake.:) Though apparently these days the spelling with two s's is becoming the norm rather then the exception (at least according to the grammarist, n-grams still has the correct version about 3 times more popular).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Lost travellers in Egypt get just deserts."

1. There is  syntactic ambiguity because *just* can be adjective or adverb.

   (a) They get just deserts --->  They just get deserts ---> They only get deserts (adverb)

   (b)  They get just deserts ---> They get rightful deserts (adjective)
2. There is lexical ambiguity because 'just' has more than one meaning and 'deserts' has more than one meaning. If English spelling allowed stress markers ('des-ert v des'ert) then lexical ambiguity would apply only to 'just'.
3. There is semantic ambiguity of the whole sentence both from (a) and (b)

**Note**
just
http://sites.macewan.ca/bcsblog/2012/01/31/teaching-grammar-point-watch-out-for-the-word-just/

Answer (score 6):

Consider a reasonable definition of *[lexical ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguity#Linguistic_forms)*:

> The lexical ambiguity of a word or phrase pertains to it's having more than one meaning in the language to which the word belongs.
>   <sub>*wikipedia, **emphasis** added*</sub>

There seems to be some lexical ambiguity in the **spoken** sentence:

> Lost travelers in Egypt get just **des[s]erts.**

Is the object of *get* to be understood as *desserts* or *deserts*?  Is the word I hear spelled with one *s*, which carries me to *desert* in the lexicon, or with two, which carries me to *dessert* in the lexicon? The phonetic structure does not offer sufficient information to answer the question, so it seems like the **primary** ambiguity is *[morphophonemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphophonology)*:

> the ***interaction*** between morphological and phonological or phonetic
>   processes.
>   <sub>*wikipedia, **emphasis** added*</sub>

The secondary lexical ambiguity arises from the morphophonemic ambiguity, and a tertiary *syntactic ambiguity* arises from that. Is *just* functioning as an adjective modifying *dessert*, or as an adverb modifying *get*? Once the lexical ambiguity and the syntactic ambiguity are resolve, the issue of *[semantic ambiguity](http://cs.nyu.edu/faculty/davise/ai/ambiguity.html)* is irrelevant:

> Even ***after the syntax and the meanings of the individual words have
>   been resolved***, there are two ways of reading the sentence ... John and
>   Mary are married. (To each other? or separately?)
>   <sub>*Notes on Ambiguity, by Ernest Davis, **emphasis** added*</sub>

But wait! The ambiguity is obviously contrived by craft or ignorance. If it is craft, the listener understands that travelers lost in the desert are likely to run out of ***desserts*** before they run out of other food--even if food is rationed for a time. The sentence smacks of a pun and we chuckle: it's hardly sensible to interpret what we heard as *desserts*, so *just* is probably not an adverb in this sentence!

On the other hand, if a native speaker had intended to indicate *appropriate punishment*, the sentence would have been spoken [*idiomatically*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+just+deserts):

> Lost travelers in Egypt get **their** just deserts.

Leading the noun phrase with the possessive pronoun *their* eliminates all the ambiguity. *Just* is clearly an adjective modifying the noun *deserts*. Ultimately, we realize that omitting *their* was a syntactic error creating *[**syntactic ambiguity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity)*:

> also called ***amphiboly*** or ***amphibology***, is a situation where a sentence may be interpreted in more than one way
>   due to ambiguous sentence structure.
>   <sub>*wikipedia, **emphasis** added*</sub>

**Conclusion:**

The semantic conundrum was a syntactic *just* riddle wrapped in the lexical mystery of *des[s]ert* inside a morphophonemic enigma. The key is the missing *their*! Whether intentional or inadvertent, that syntactic error was the primary source of the ambiguity.

---

The expression *just deserts* actually comes from an archaic noun form of the word *[deserve](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=desert&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> "suitable reward or punishment" (now usually plural and with just), c.
>   1300, from Old French deserte, noun use of past participle of deservir
>   "be worthy to have," ultimately from Latin deservire "serve well"
>
> (see *[deserve](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=deserve&allowed_in_frame=0)*).
>
> early 13c., from Old French deservir (Modern French desservir)
>   "deserve, be worthy of, earn, merit," from Latin deservire "serve
>   well," from de- "completely" (see de-) + servire "to serve" (see
>   *serve*). From "be entitled to because of good service" (a sense found
>   in Late Latin), meaning generalized c. 1300 to "be worthy of."
>   Related: Deserved; deserving.
>
> [*serve*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=serve&allowed_in_frame=0)
>   late 12c., "to render habitual obedience to," also "minister, give aid, give help," from Old French servir "to do duty toward, show devotion to; set table, serve at table; offer, provide with," from Latin servire "be a servant, be in service, be enslaved;" figuratively "be devoted; be governed by; comply with; conform; flatter," originally "be a slave," related to servus "slave," perhaps from Etruscan (compare Etruscan proper names Servi, Serve, Latinized as Servius).
>
> By c. 1200 also as "to be in the service of, perform a service for;
>   attend upon, be personal servant to; be a slave; owe allegiance to;
>   officiate at Mass or other religious rites;" from early 13c. as "set
>   food at table;" mid-14c. as "to wait on (customers)." From late 14c.
>   as "treat (someone or something) in some fashion." To serve (someone)
>   right "to treat as he deserves" is recorded from 1580s.
>
> He no schuld neuer wond  To seruen him fro fot to hond  ["Amis and
>   Amiloun," c. 1330]
>
> Sense of "be useful, be beneficial, be suitable for a purpose or
>   function" is from early 14c.; that of "take the place or meet the
>   needs of, be equal to the task" is from late 14c.; that of "suffice"
>   is from mid-15c. Meaning "render active military service" is from
>   1510s. Sporting sense, in tennis, badminton, etc., first recorded
>   1580s. Legal sense "present" (a writ, warrant,etc.), "give legal
>   notice of" is from early 15c.
>   <sub>*etymonline.com*</sub>

This noun form of *deserve* is not related etymologically to either of its homographs, [*desert*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=desert&allowed_in_frame=0) [depart] or [desert](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=desert&allowed_in_frame=0) [arid], but it is related to its homophone *[dessert](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dessert&allowed_in_frame=0)* through an ancient connection to *serve*:

> c. 1600, from Middle French dessert (mid-16c.) "last course,"
>   literally "removal of what has been served," from desservir "clear the
>   table," literally "un-serve," from des- "remove, undo" (see dis-) +
>   Old French servir "to serve" (see *[serve](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=serve&allowed_in_frame=0)* (v.)).
>   <sub>*etymonline.com*</sub>

Though *desert* is related etymologically to its homophone, *dessert* it would not be *[polysemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy)*, because the senses are no longer related lexically:

> a word or phrase with different, but ***related senses***.
>   <sub>*wikipedia, **emphasis** added*</sub>

Because *desert* is not spelled like its homophone *dessert*, it would not be *[homonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym)*:

> a word that has different meanings. In the strict sense, one of a
>   group of words that ***share the same spelling and pronunciation*** but have
>   different meanings.
>   <sub>*wikipedia, **emphasis** added*</sub>

As the OP conceded, there is no *lexical ambiguity* in the written words because they are spelled differently, but any ambiguity of interpretation would be rooted in the fact that they are *[homophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone)*:

> a word that is pronounced the same as another word but differs in
>   meaning, and may differ in spelling.
>   <sub>*wikipedia*</sub>

Comment: You deserve a dessert for that one!

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for this tour de force. In particular you’ve shown me a difference between *‘amphiboly,* *amphibology’* and *‘syntactic* *ambiguity;’* and introduced me to morphophonemics. Many thanks also for observations on the shared roots of *deserve,* *deserts,* *dessert.*  Apologies for slow response::